# Javascript - Undefined arrays in iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am working on a Nodejs tool which uses an API.
My issue is that I don't understand why the previous element of the array is not registered properly and is "Undefined" when the iterator is incremented.

```
  this.pptab = new Array();
  this.tabplayers = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < (argsname.length - 1); i++) {
    osuApi.getUser({ "u": argsname[i], "m": argsmode.join('=') }).then(user => { //calling the osu!api
      this.pptab[i] = user[0].pp_raw;
      this.tabplayers[i] = user[0].username;
      console.log("Player -1: " + this.tabplayers[i - 1]); // This displays "Undefined" in each iteration
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you realize, that for the first iterated element (at index 0) the expression calculates -1 and uses that as index to access, _and that no element at that index was defined yet_?

Comment: Thank you, I edited the code so the iterator starts at 1 and I initialized the first element of the array but it still keeps showing "undefined"...

Comment: @bastoo0 you will still have the same issue as the index [0] wouldn't be defined neither

Comment: you can only access the value of `this.tabplayers[i - 1]` when the iteration is not the first (in your case)

Comment: What is contained within the argsname array?

Comment: It's the command "!topsetup Player1 Player2 Player3 m=2", splitted on each space character and with a shift on the first index. So it gives an array of "Player1" "Player2" "Player3" "m=2", that's why I use "argsname.length - 1"

Answer (score 0):

Two issue one in loop condition `[  i **<** (argsname.length-1)]` you do not require (-1 ) as of smaller then condition. Second if condition required for first step.

```
  this.pptab = new Array();
  this.tabplayers = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < (argsname.length); i++) {
    osuApi.getUser({ "u": argsname[i], "m": argsmode.join('=') }).then(user => { //calling the osu!api
      this.pptab[i] = user[0].pp_raw;
      this.tabplayers[i] = user[0].username;
      if(i>0) {
           console.log("Player -1: " + this.tabplayers[i-1]); // for first player -1 does not exist
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I use (argsname.length - 1) purposely since my array has an element which I don't use. It's an array of "Player1" "Player2" "Player3" "m=2", that's why I use "argsname.length - 1". So I tried using your code but I still have the issue, I'm starting to think that it could be from a bad use of "this"

Comment: yes , initialization of object value should be without this . as per 
"JavaScript strict mode does not allow default binding. So, when used in a function, in strict mode, this is undefined."

please refer " https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp "

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong when converting your string command to an array and then shifting it. See this:

Code is here:
https://repl.it/@LatinWarrior/StackoverflowQuestion

This is what I wrote:

```
let argsname = "!topsetup Player1 Player2 Player3 m=2".split(' ');
let argsnameWithShift = argsname.shift();

console.log(argsname);
console.log(argsnameWithShift);
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/m1ylqi Is this what I am supposed to get? I don't get why before the shift I don't have "!topsetup" in the first index...

Comment: I suggest you append an empty string to the beginning of the string and you will get what you want, like so: let argsname = " !topsetup Player1 Player2 Player3 m=2".split(' ').shift();